# Java: unwanted characters at the beginning of a file as result of serialization

Tags: java

when I write a new text file in Java, I get these characters at the beginning of the file:

```
¨Ìt
```

This is the code:

```
public static void writeMAP(String filename, Object object) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
}
```

thanks

Comment: _how_ do you write the text file?

Comment: This is not a text file. You are serializing objects using ObjectOutputStream, so you can't expect the content to be text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Writer output = null;
String text = "Www.criandcric.com. is my site";
File file = new File("write.txt");
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
output.write(text);
output.close();
```

I hope with this You can get an idea how to do that.

Comment: And what is, if i want to use an object and not a string?

Answer (score 4):

ObjectOutputStreams are *not* meant for writing "text files."  They are used specifically for writing an intermediate representation of Java objects out to disk.  This process is known as serialization.

You most likely want to use a Writer, which is more useful for making human-readable text files.  In particular, you should look at [FileWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and/or [PrintWriter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

Answer (score 3):

When using `ObjectOutputStream` you make binary serialization of your object. You aren't supposed to view the file as a "text file" at all.

If you want to serialize your object in a human-readable way, use [`java.beans.XMLEncoder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html). Read the linked docs on how to use it in a similar way to `ObjectOutputStream`. It produces XML.

Answer (score 2):

You're not writing text to the file, you're writing objects to it, which means you get a stream header, type information and internal structure. To write text, use a Writer:

```
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), encoding);
```

Comment: It's probably cleaner to use a FileWriter to write text, to simplify non-ASCII encoding handling.

Comment: @Steven: FileWriter is useless exactly because it does *not* allow proper handling of encodings at all - it will always use the platform default encoding.