# Writing JSONObject into a file

Tags: java, json, file, file-io

I'm using Play framework. I have a JSONObject which has a structure like the below (As in console it printed)

```
{
    "rows_map":{
        "220":["mahesh",
            "outfit:bmtech,app:salesreport,uuname,ffname,llname",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5",
            null
        ],
"221":["mahesh",
            "outfit:bmtech,app:salesreport,uuname,ffname,llname",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5",
            null
        ],
"222":["mahesh",
            "outfit:bmtech,app:salesreport,uuname,ffname,llname",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5",
            null
        ],
"223":["mahesh",
            "outfit:bmtech,app:salesreport,uuname,ffname,llname",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5",
            null
        ]
},
    "columns_map":["Sender",
        "Message Received",
        "Device",
        "Time"
    ]
}
```

I want to write this JSONObject to a file. Here is the code

```
String path = "/var/www/html/Prj/public/CacheLayer/Incoming_Cache/CacheFileMgr.cache";

            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try{
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
            System.out.println("Start Writings");
                outputStream.writeObject(object);
                outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
          }catch (Exception e){
          System.err.println("Error: " + e);
          }
```

The above doesn't successfully writes to the file. Serialization error occurs.

Comment: Please post the error message along with the code. It could be a permissions error, or it could be something as simple as `JSONObject` does not implement the `Serializable` interface, which is what is required in order for `.writeObject()` to work (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call toString on the JSONObject, and then serialize the string. JSONObject itself is not serializable.

```
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, using toString is sucessfully writing to the file. At the start it is appending these characters ��. In the console it was not there. What is this and how could i ignore this.

Comment: Okay i found the solution here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801305/java-unwanted-characters-at-the-beginning-of-a-file-as-result-of-serialization

Comment: For a big json object, we call `toString()` it may take awhile

Answer (score 7):

JSON is the serialization, it doesn't implement serializable, just convert it to string and save the string in a file (as text).